# having trouble with this well known fact $ab | a^2 + b^2 +1 =>a^2 + b^2 +1 = 3ab $

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

I have seen people use this without proof as a well known fact.

Can someone give a proof or a reference?

Comment: Do you know the Vieta root jumping technique?

Comment: found it on Wikipedia, they have this as an example.  
copy the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the Vieta root jumping technique?

---

Here is a [problem](http://brilliant.org/i/uFOKQU/) for you to try, using the same technique.

Comment: can't read the problem

Comment: @BojanSerafimov Hm, what issue are you having? Try expanding your screen, that might help. The question asks you to determine pairs of non negative integers from 1 to 100, such that $ n \mid m^2 -1, m \mid n^2 -1 $.

Comment: I tried firefox and chrome, both fullscreen, everything's there, just the text of the problem is missing.

Comment: @BojanSerafimov I'd look into it. Here's a [screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/3S3n1G1M3K3s)

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna take some time.

Comment: I can't solve it, I wrote a c++ program :D

Comment: @BojanSerafimov Use the idea of Vieta root jumping. Given a solution $(n, m)$, try and reduce it to something 'smaller'.

Comment: if(x, y) is a solution, y > x > 1, (y, (y^2-1)/x) is a solution.
So we can make an array with a[0] = 1, a[1] = k, a[i] = (a[i-1]-1)/a[i-2], for every k <= 100, and every consecutive pair will be a solution

Comment: @BojanSerafimov That's great! You see how the Vieta's jumping helps approach the problem pretty directly. The tricky part would then be ensuring that you cover all base cases and count correctly.

Comment: @BojanSerafimov It looks like it might be a Windows cache issue. Try removing toolbars or using IE 9 or 10, instead of firefox 20.0.

Comment: no it worked out by itself, i just waited a minute or two, probably because the latex was compiling, or because I use and experimental version of Firefox. I registered on the site, its very helpful, just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both $a,\,b\in\mathbb{N}$.

Consider for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $a^2+b^2+1=kab$.

Note that $k\neq 1,2$ because

$a^2+b^2+1\geq 2ab+1>2ab>ab$.

I was hoping to do something similar for $k>3$ also but it doesn't work...

Comment: I thought you just gave me a hint xD

The same cant be done, because $a^2 + b^2$ can be much greater than $ab$, for example when $b=1$